# Delete an item from a Dictionary and then save it to the NSManagedObject in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I'm new to Swift and I'm making an application to account expenses using Core Data and SwiftUI. The problem is that when I try to delete items from the List, it does not do so in the correct index. Probably because I applied a method that groups the items from the FetchRequest by date in a dictionary and displays them in the UI by Sections.

So, when I have rewritten the delete function so that it now takes the new indexes, I get an error that says: "Cannot convert value of type '[ExpenseLog]' to expected argument type 'NSManagedObject'", because I have previously made the change to the Dictionary.

Is there a way to be able to delete Core Data items by keeping the group by sections?
Because If I delete the ForEach that creates the Sections, the index is correct again and I can remove the correct item from Core Data. But that's not really what I want.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct LogListView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\ExpenseLog.date, order: .reverse)]) var logs: FetchedResults<ExpenseLog>
    
    @State var logToEdit: ExpenseLog?
    @State var searchText = ""
    
    var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .long
        return formatter
    }
    
    var sections: [[ExpenseLog]] {
        ExpenseLog.update(Array(logs), and: dateFormatter)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(sections, id: \.self) { (section: [ExpenseLog]) in
                Section(header: Text(dateFormatter.string(from: section[0].date!))) {
                    ForEach(section.filter({
                        self.searchText.isEmpty ? true :
                        $0.name!.localizedStandardContains(self.searchText)
                    }), id: \.id) { log in
                        Button {
                            logToEdit = log
                        } label: {
                            HStack(spacing: 16) {
                                CategoryIconsView(category: log.categoryEnum)
                                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                                    Text(log.nameText).font(.subheadline)
                                    Text(log.dataText)
                                }
                                Spacer()
                                Text(log.typeTransaction != "expensive" ? log.amountText : "-\(log.amountText)").font(.subheadline).foregroundColor(log.typeTransaction == "income" ? .green : .primary)
                            }
                            .padding(.vertical, 4)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .onDelete(perform: deleteItem)
        }
    }
    
     func deleteItem(at offsets: IndexSet) {
         var sec = sections
         sec.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
         
         offsets.forEach { index in
             let log = sec[index]
             moc.delete(log) // Error: Cannot convert value of type '[ExpenseLog]' to expected argument type 'NSManagedObject'
         
        try? moc.saveContext()
    }
```

And here is the method that groups the FetchedResults by dates in the ExpensesLog extension.

```
static func update(_ result: [ExpenseLog], and dateFormatter: DateFormatter) -> [[ExpenseLog]] {
        return Dictionary(grouping: result) { (element : ExpenseLog)  in
            dateFormatter.string(from: element.date!)
        }.values.sorted() { $0[0].date! > $1[0].date! }
    }
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You don’t have a dictionary, you have an array of arrays. I don’t think you need that at all here and can work with a simple array by using a [SectionedFetchRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/SectionedFetchRequest) then your delete issue should resolve itself

Comment: Thank you for answering! I have tried SectionedFetchRequest before but the problem I encountered is that although they were grouped by sections, if there are two transactions with the same date they were not grouped within the same section, but two different sections were created with the same date. That's why I've tried to group it with the method. Am I missing something?

Comment: A date also contains time so that is why they are almost always different. Add a computed property that either formats the date to a string as you already do or use the Calendar function startOfDay that sets the time part to zero. Then use this computed property for the Section